I want to fit and clip/crop an image inside a div which is a grid element as well. I have tried using "overflow" but it does not work
So, I am trying to complete a bento grid challenge from my frontend mentor. In one part, it requires me to clip/crop an image element, and it should not overlap outside the div. I am allowed to use only HTML and CSS for it. Many people have used Tailwind for this, but I am trying to create it from scratch.
This is what I have gotten to:



  .bento3 > img {
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 14px;
  }
<!-- This div is in a grid container   -->
    <div class="box bento3">
      <h2>Maintain a consistent posting schedule.</h2>
      <img src="./assets/images/illustration-consistent-schedule.webp">
    </div>  



This is what it should actually look like:

Keep in mind this is not cropping. The image should come up with different screen sizes. For example if I reduce the screen size it looks like this:
For 768px screen size:

For 610px screen size:

Let me know what I should do to achieve this.

I'm unclear on some details - in particular, what has background-size got to do with anything and I can't see where you've tried to hide the overflow.? I think it would help us help you if you could create a runnable snippet which shows the problem. This will need to include the parent (grid) element. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Give your image the desired width and height, then use things like object-fit to fit it inside that box and object-position to align it with an edge.

It looks like you're trying to ensure that the image fits and clips correctly within the grid element while . The issue likely arises because the overflow property isn’t set on the parent container to handle clipping.
.bento3 {
  display: grid; 

  overflow: hidden;
}

.bento3 > img {

  width: 100%;

  height: 100%;  

  object-fit: cover;  

  margin-top: 14px; 
}


Have you tried this? You are using cover but the OP has talked about clipping overflow and (depending on various dimensions) cover will not achieve the same cropping as is required.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
